# How to compute the difference between counts after grouping?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I got data in group into format: (GroupID, count). Like the following, I would like to compute the difference between the count, meanwhile preserve the GroupID. So, it becomes (1, 288) (2, 2), (3,66)....
I tried to use the SUBTRACT function, but not sure how to subtract the previous record from the current one. The second image shows the count part. The subtraction part is failed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little tricky to achieve but can be done using a JOIN.Generate another relation starting with the second row but with ID 1 i.e ($0-1).Join the 2 relations and generate the difference.For Id add 1 to get the original ids.Union the the 1st row with the rows that contain the difference.

```
A = foreach win_grouped generate $0 as id,count($1) as c; -- (1,228),(2,230)... so on
A1 = filter A by ($0 > 1);                                -- (2,230),(3,296)... so on
B = foreach A1 generate ($0 - 1) as id,$1 as c;           -- (1,230),(2,296)... so on
AB = join A by id,B by id;                                -- (1,228,1,230),(2,230,2,296)...so on
C = foreach AB generate (A::id + 1),(B::c - A::c)         -- (2,2),(3,66)...so on
D = limit A 1;                                            -- (1,288)
E = UNION D,C;                                            -- (1,288),(2,2),(3,66)...so on
DUMP E;
```

Comment: I have already tried it, everything is good except the C = foreach AB generate (A.$0 + 1),(B.$1 - A.$1); It leads to an "Scalar has more than one row in the input". Solution is, instead of using dot operator use :: operator instead. A::id, B::c...